# Visual Studio Web Deployment project breaks ASPNET account permissions

Tags: asp.net, custom-action, web-deployment-project, iis-5

I have built an ASP.NET web application with Visual Studio 2008 and target framework version 2.0. I have created a Web Setup project to deploy this at multiple target OSes.

For the setup project, I have written a custom action which gets executed on "OnCommitting" event. This custom action adds wildcard script mapping for routing all requests through ASP.NET engine.

FileMon suggests that an error occurs while creating a file in the following directory:
    C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files

The user account which was attempting this action was IWAM_<host name>.

The problem is after running this setup, if I try to access any url on the newly installed site, I received the error message:

## Server Error in '/myapp' Application.

### *Failed to access IIS metabase.*

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
 **Exception Details:** System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironmentException: Failed to access IIS metabase.

**The process account used to run ASP.NET must have read access to the IIS metabase (e.g. IIS://servername/W3SVC).   For information on modifying metabase permissions, please see http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=267904.**
**Source Error:**

`An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.`

I have already tried these options after 2 days of googling:

1. Run aspnet_regiis -i
2. Run aspnet_regiis -ga \ASPNET
3. Run aspnet_regiis -u and then aspnet_regiis -i

Option 3 has worked for me as of now, but, I want avoid using this, since, my web app will be deployed on a machine which might already be hosting some other app on IIS and I do not want to disturb these apps.

Can anyone suggest me a workaround for this?

B.T.W. my current system has .Net framework 3.5 and VS2008 installed on Win XP SP3 and IIS 5.1.

Thanks,
Vamyip

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is a custom bit of script in the installer package that checks permissions and then runs the command based on that information.

On a server OS this shouldn't be necessary since the default user for the application group will be in the IIS_WPG and have permissions to the temp directories. Windows XP has a bugged up version of IIS that is non-standard and doesn't follow all the rules. If your expected deployment environment is Windows Server 2003 or better then your installer should work as-is.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My target OSes includes Win XP, Vista and 7 from desktop OS and Win 2000, Win 2003, Win 2008 and Win 2008 R2 for server front. Can you elaborate about running command based on permissions? Thanks again